# Loop over all tables in am HTML document

Tags: javascript, .net, html-table, css-tables, portability

I'm looking for a way to loop over all of the tables in a given HTML document. The document is an automatically generated report that could have as few as 1 and up to thousands of generated tables within it that I need to be able to filter from a single keyword search field. The requirements are a bit strange:

- This is a portable HTML document that will be run entirely offline inside of a browser or WebBrowser .NET control. I cannot assume any kind of external network connection.
- Script must be pure and relatively concise JavaScript that will live inside of each instance of the html document.
- I'm open to solutions for either `<table>` or `display:table` CSS formatted tables.
- Speed isn't terribly important.

What are my options here?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("table"), ...)`

Comment: ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Mouser I just learned the other day that [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) was added to NodeList, though not supported by older browsers.

Comment: @ProfessorAllman, indeed, how joyeus. However no Edge yet.

Comment: I should clarify that I need to (unfortunately) support at least IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript iteration will be the best solution for you. I wrote an example code, I guess it will help you out.

```js
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  var table = tables[i];
  var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
    var text = tds[j].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br>
<h1>The Parsed Output</h1>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Works like a charm.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("tabl‌​e td"), function(element){document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += element.textContent+ "<br />"})` would greatly improve this script.